# How can I change button color when clicked

Tags: html, jquery

To be brief, i have two buttons that have the same class, one of them have an attribute `data-toggle='modal'`. I use this attribute to detect the button.

I need to change the color of the button which does not have an attribute `data-toggle`, I can't target it by using the className, because they both have the same.

In the js click function, I use a ternary condition to say: if the button has an attribute '`data-toggle`' then do nothing, else removeClass `btn--ghost` and addClass `btn--plain`. But it doesn't work.

PS: the `btn--plain` is the class name used to give the button a bgcolor instead of `btn--ghost`.

This is the js :

```
if ($('.o-block-global .btn--link').length) {
    $('.btn--primary').on("click", function (e) {
        console.log("iiiiii", $(this));
        $(this).attr("data-toggle" ? "" : $(this).removeClass("btn--ghost").addClass("btn--plain"));
    });
}
```

This is the HTML :

```
<div class="o-block-global__links link_choice "> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn--ghost btn--primary">
        OUI   
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn--ghost btn--primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalChoice2"> 
        NON    
    </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why not target only those without the attribute? `$('.btn--primary:not([data-toggle])').on('click', function (e) { $(this).toggleClass('btn--ghost btn--plain'); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `attr` value is `undefined` or not using `(typeof $(this).attr("data-toggle")) !== 'undefined'`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.btn--primary').on("click", function(e) {
  //check if the attr type is not undefined
  (typeof $(this).attr("data-toggle")) !== 'undefined' ? "" : $(this).removeClass("btn--ghost").addClass("btn--plain");
});
```

```css
.btn--ghost {
  color: red;
}

.btn--plain {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-block-global__links link_choice ">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn--ghost btn--primary">
        OUI   
  </button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn--ghost btn--primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalChoice2"> 
    NON    
  </button>
```

Comment: Hey Swati, why do you use typeof ?

Comment: Just to check typeof of value .It will return `string` or any data type or `undefined` if the value doesn't exist .Also , check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for more details

Comment: Thank you @Swati is there also a way to remove the color when you click on the button 'non' ?

Comment: Yes you can put that part of code in place of `""` i.e : `(typeof $(this).attr("data-toggle")) !== 'undefined' ? $(this).css('color' , '') : $(this).removeClass("btn--ghost").addClass("btn--plain");` or if using class `(typeof $(this).attr("data-toggle")) !== 'undefined' ? $(this).removeClass("btn--ghost") : $(this).removeClass("btn--ghost").addClass("btn--plain");`

Comment: that remove the color from the button 'non', i need to remove it from button 'oui' when you click on button 'non' ><

Comment: oh i see then use `$(".btn--primary").not($(this)).css("color", "")` in place of `""` or if using class then `$(".btn--primary").not($(this)).removeClass("classnamehere")`

Comment: THank you it works, i need just a way to apply that just for these two buttons, because i have other buttons 'oui' and 'non' in my front page and it affects them :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231460/discussion-between-swati-and-mitsu).

Answer (score 0):

To do that you use the `:active selector`. HTML:

```
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

```
button{
    background:green;
}
button:hover{
    background:lightgreen;
}
button:active{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: i need to target the button which does not have an attribute data-toggle